# Unsupported codec for Media3 ExoPlayer

Tags: kotlin, exoplayer, android-media3

In my project I use **Media3 ExoPlayer** to play video.

**Problem**: the stream I want to play is probably not supported.

Links to some other streams work.

`build.gradle.kts`:

```
...
// Media3 ExoPlayer
    implementation("androidx.media3:media3-exoplayer:1.0.1")
    implementation("androidx.media3:media3-exoplayer-dash:1.0.1")
    implementation("androidx.media3:media3-ui:1.0.1")
...
```

`activity_main.xml`:

```
...
    <androidx.media3.ui.PlayerView
        android:id="@+id/player"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="16:9"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
...
```

**Code for create MediaSource**:

```
...
val mediaSource = DashMediaSource
        .Factory(DefaultHttpDataSource.Factory())
        .createMediaSource(MediaItem.Builder()
            .setUri(url)
            .setMimeType(MimeTypes.APPLICATION_MPD)
            .build())

exoPlayer = ExoPlayer
        .Builder(context)
        .build()
        .apply{
trackSelectionParameters = trackSelectionParameters
                .buildUpon()
                .setMaxVideoSizeSd()
                .build()
            addAnalyticsListener(EventLogger())
            setMediaSource(mediaSource)
            prepare()
}
binding.player.player = exoPlayer
...
```

In the rest of the code, I don’t see the point, since other videos are played. Therefore, I apply the problematic video codec from `manifest.mpd`:

```
<Representation
          id="f3-v1-x3"
          mimeType="video/webm"
          codecs="av01.0.04M.08"
          width="854"
          height="480"
          frameRate="1000/41"
          sar="1:1"
          startWithSAP="1"
          bandwidth="429310">
      </Representation>
```

**What I see**?

1. The player has audio (due to additional `AdaptationSet`);
2. There is no picture in the player.

**What I think**?

Since other videos with different codecs work fine and based on my observations, namely I looked at what `MimeTypes.getVideoMediaMimeType("av01.0.04M.08")` would return an empty array, and for some other codecs, it returns a non-empty one.

I believe that the codec is not supported.

Please tell me, if I am not mistaken in my assumption, how can I add support for this codec to exoPlayer?

Answer (score 0):

```
av01.0.04M.08
```

is the [AV1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AV1) and you device not have hardware support.

You can try use media3 locally with programmatically support.
Instruction [on github of media3 library](https://github.com/androidx/media/tree/release/libraries/decoder_av1)

Also you need configure NDK, CMAKE. About it write in instruction.